# Linux not running DHCP upon connecting to new VLAN

Tags: dhclient

So I have autossh running on a Linux system, and it's configured to re-connect to my SSH server if it gets disconnected. I can confirm that this works by simply unplugging the NIC and plugging it back up. Works just fine.

However, if I change the VLAN that the Linux system is on, the system doesn't ever re-connect because it doesn't seem to be automatically running dhclient.

Is there a process or something that I need to start so that it can detect when the NIC's connectivity state changes and run dhclient again?

I'm already running NetworkManager and dhclient, but it still doesn't help upon network changes.

Comment: Maybe udev rules would help.

Comment: Have you configured `interface` in the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`? You may need to specify something like `eth0:100`.

Comment: Does the VLAN change cause a link failure or anything that the Linux system could detect? If not, and there is more than half of the DHCP lease time still left, the system has no reason to do anything: it has a valid DHCP lease and the link is still on. Some switches will automatically force the network port to a disabled state for a few seconds when changing VLAN settings, just to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just getting this resolved by installing netplug and enabling its service:

```
sudo apt install netplug
sudo service netplug start
```

That's it. Now switching VLANs or unplugging and plugging up into another network will cause the system to obtain another DHCP IP again if DHCP is being used.